# encoding dataset for Aprori algorithm

Tags: python, encoding, apriori

[encoding table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMqVD.jpg)

Hi everyone;
I have a dataset with 48 variables and about 50,000 records. When I want to encode to apply the Apriori algorithm, this is the answer that I attached. It doesn't get the names of the columns and besides it doesn't do it right at all. more clearly, if we have 5 unique data in each feature on average, it should output 5*48 columns, but it doesn't.
Thank you for your guidance.

my code:

```py
T2=T11.copy()
transactionEncoder = TransactionEncoder()
T3 = transactionEncoder.fit(T2).transform(T2)

df = pd.DataFrame(T3 ,columns=transactionEncoder.columns_)
df = df.replace(False,0)
df
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: T2=T11.copy()
transactionEncoder = TransactionEncoder()
T3 = transactionEncoder.fit(T2).transform(T2) 
df = pd.DataFrame(T3 ,columns=transactionEncoder.columns_)
df = df.replace(False,0)
df